# visual studio code when command line arguments added in launch.json breakpoints don't get hit

Tags: c, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

***SEE BOTTOM FOR EDIT*

I am trying to debug a C program in VS Code but the break point is not hitting. I had a similar problem in another program i was debugging last week and I moved the code to another file, opened the file up in VS Code and the break points worked fine. 
Therefore, Im thinking it is an error on my end but I cant figure out what it is.
Most of the things I read on stack overflow is people forgetting to add the -g when compiling.
These are a couple of the resources I have looked at:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1685

teeCommand.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define handle_error(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fileLength;
int inputFd, outputFd;
char* buffer;
ssize_t numRead;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

if(argc < 5){
    printf("not enough arguments given");
}

inputFd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
if(inputFd == -1){
    handle_error("opening input file");
}

outputFd = open(argv[4], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
if(outputFd == -1){
    handle_error("opening file output file");
}

while((numRead = read(inputFd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
    if(write(outputFd, buf, numRead) != numRead){
        handle_error("could not write the whole buffer");
    }
}
if(numRead == -1){
    exit(1);
}

if(close(inputFd) == -1){
    exit(1);
}
if(close(outputFd) == -1){
    exit(1);
}

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc -g teeCommand.c -o teeCommand",
        "group":{
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/teeCommand",
        "args": ["file.txt", "|", "tee", "file2.txt"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My output is:

*&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
**not enough arguments given[1] + Done**                       /usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-nwqez75o.cn0
Press any key to continue...*

so I see that it is hitting my code (by the bold print) but it is not hitting the break points I set in VS Code at the top of main()

*EDIT: I see that the issue is in my launch.json, when there are arguments added to the args property the code doesnt stop at break points. When I remove the args the code stops at the break points properly*

Comment: A quick thing to try is to disable all optimization, i.e. insert the -O0 flag. This way break points won't be skipped.

Comment: @John i tried this but unfortunately it is still not stopping at the break point

Comment: regarding; `inputFd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);`   Why the parameter: `O_CREAT` for the input file?  Also, if the input file is not readable due to its' permissions, the listing a bunch of permissions will not help.  Suggest using: `inputFd = open( argv[1], O_RDWR );`

Comment: same thing is happening to this code, when I move it to a different file in a different directory the break point works. Im not too familiar with what happens behind the scenes in the compilation. Is there a temporary debug folder that could be getting messed up?

Comment: when using `gdb`, you need to set the argument list in the `run` statement

Comment: regarding: `"command": "gcc -g teeCommand.c -o teeCommand",`  This is not enabling the compiler warnings.  suggest inserting: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: regarding: `"stopAtEntry": false,`  This will result in NO breakpoint at `main()`  Also, there are no other breakpoints set

Comment: I determined when there are command line arguments added, in the launch.json args property, the breakpoints dont get hit. I am still trying to figure out why this is or if it is a VS bug

Answer (score 0):

strongly suggest:

```
gdb teecommand
br main
r "file.txt", "|", "tee", "file2.txt"
```

which works as you expect, so the problem is in the .json script

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this does work but it does not allow me to use the tools in the VS Code GUI. Your right though, my issue is in the launch.json. When i remove the args i can hit the break point through the VS Code GUI

Comment: I don't know `json` so cannot help you with that problem